# NSMenu in separate class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am trying to keep NSMenu and NSStatusItem in a separate header file than AppDelegate.h. but when menu doesn't appear in status bar. I've created a simple project to explain the problem. You can see code http://pastebin.com/fCnYnrS2

In WinMangerController.xib I have added an NSMenu and set its title and referenced outlet is in WinMangerController.h

but when I call setup method from AppDelegate.m then menu doesn't appear at all.

Any hint to fix this?

Comment: One problem I saw is that, you do not have a reference to to `w`. After `WinManagerViewController *w = [[WinManagerViewController alloc] init];`, `w` is released.

Comment: In you case, the nib file isn't loaded at all. Hence the variable _menu is nil. This doesn't seem to be the right way to do it. What are u trying to achieve?